# Best way to handle optional inputs RESTful API in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a RESTful service that I have created for a usage database.
Required parameters are start-date & end-date. Operational parameters are user-name, client-ip & remote-ip.

I have this working but wanted to see if there is a better way to implement:

Here is my resource class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/usage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation(value = "Usage Sessions - JSON Body", notes = "GET method for users by date range")
public List<DTO> getUsageByDate(@RequestParam(value = "start-date", required = true) final String startDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "end-date", required = true) final String endDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "user-name", required = false) final String userName,
        @RequestParam(value = "client-ip", required = false) final String clientIp,
        @RequestParam(value = "remote-ip", required = false) final String nasIp) throws BadParameterException {
    return aaaService.findUsageByDate(startDate, endDate, userName, clientIp,remoteIp);

}
```

My DAO implementation looks like:

```
public List<DTO> getUsageByDate(String startDate, String endDate, String userName, String localIp, String remoteIp)
        throws BadParameterException {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(
            "select * from usage where process_time >= :start_date and process_time < :end_date");

    if(userName != null) {
        sql.append(" AND user_name = :user_name");
    }
    if(localIp != null) {
        sql.append(" AND local_ip_address = :local_ip");
    }
    if(remoteIp != null){
        sql.append(" AND remote_ip_address = :remote_ip");
    }

    SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("start_date", startDate)
            .addValue("end_date", endDate).addValue("user_name", userName).addValue("local_ip", localIp)
            .addValue("nas_ip", remoteIp);

    try {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql.toString(), namedParameters,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<DTO>(DTO.class));

    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        throw new BadParameterException();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts seems a little long winded right now.

Thanks

Comment: required = true is the default. For those parameters that are optional, you do not need to add the required attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  On the implementation with the if statements is there a better way?

Comment: I usually do this via JSR303. Have you considered this option?

Comment: dambros, my service is a pure GET. The usage table I refer to is being generated by another source. I am not sure how JSR303 will help here

Comment: JSR303 will help if you create a POJO object to which the request params are bound. With JSR303 annotations on this POJO your method  becomes: public List<DTO> getUsageByDate(@Valid @ModelAttribute SomePojo request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make the required parameters (start-date, end-date) part of the URI and for the optional parameters (user-name, client-ip, remote-ip) use query parameters. So you URI might be `/usage/05.05.2015/06.06.2016?user-name=Joe`.
2. User input validation should not be done in your DAO. It should be done in the REST controller.
3. You can express which parameters are optional and which are mandatory in the `getUsageByDate` method signature if you use Java 8:

   ```
    public List<DTO> getUsageByDate(String startDate, String endDate,
         Optional<String> userName, Optional<String> localIp, Optional<String> remoteIp)
   ```
4. You should also validate the required parameters are provided:

   ```
   Objects.requireNonNull(startDate);
   Objects.requireNonNull(endDate);
   ```
5. You should make sure the dates provided by the user are valid and also you should not be passing a date to your DAO as a String.

Comment: Your (1) removes the ability to later decide that a date parameter is optional.

Comment: @EricStein That is correct. It is a tradeoff between a REST API expressiveness and an ability to freely change it.